# Invoke imap socket request for another user

Tags: sockets, imap

Does the imap protocol support logging in with one particular account and then seeing the inbox count for another user.   For example, let's say you login with an admin account and then want to check the inbox values for a particular user id.

*"status INBOX (UNSEEN)"*

Comment: That would be an server extension. The standard protocol only allows logging in as one user, and seeing his mailboxes.   If your server software has admin users, you may be able to see other users mailboxes in other places in the folder list structure. For example they may show up as shared folders,   see the `NAMESPACE` extension. This will be server specific so you will need to check its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IMAP does](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4959), but your server doesn't have to unless it reports the `AUTH=PLAIN` capability.

You can then log in with [PLAIN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616) impersonation:

```
AuthString = Base64(UserToImpersonate+\0+ActualUser+\0+ActualUsersPassword);
```

And send the command:

```
a002 AUTHENTICATE "PLAIN" AuthString
```

Comment: That might work.   I saw something else where I could send the login with a wildcard to the user I was interested.  E.g. server.login("user*admin", "adminpassword")

Comment: Sasl-ir is not required. You would need to provide authoring as a response after doing `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN`. SASL-IR just reduced the round trips.

Answer (score 0):

Support for `AUTH=PLAIN` does *not* mandate support for user impersonation. I.e. even if your server supports the PLAIN SASL authentication method, there is no guarantee that it supports the concept of a superuser who can "switch" to another user.